# How do I hide the System Reserved partition?

Tags: windows, windows-8-preview, system-reserved-partition

How do I hide the System Reserved partition from the Windows Explorer?

[image]

On the above screenshot, I want to get rid of `System Reserved (D:)`. How do I do that?

*I will never need to access it from there, why would I need the entry then?*

**PS:** I want to hide it, not delete it.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Remove the drive letter for the system reserved partition. If you have a multi-boot system, this *could* cause problems depending on where your system boots from.

To remove the drive letter and hide the partition from explorer and my computer:

1. Open Computer management on the local computer by right clicking on `Computer` in Windows Explorer and choose `manage`. Then click on `Disk Management` in the left hand pane.

   (Or just type `diskmgmt.msc` into the run dialog)
2. Right click on the shaded area for `Drive D: System reserved` in the lower right hand window.
3. Click on `Change drive letter or paths`
4. Highlight `D` and click `remove`

If you receive error messages that the drive might be in use or that programs might not run correctly, **don't panic**.  It is OK to remove the drive letter. Once a letter is not assigned, the drive will not appear in windows explorer.

This works in Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 10.

Comment: "If you have a multi-boot system, this could cause problems depending on where your system boots from. " <- could you elaborate on that part? In what circumstances might that cause problems, and why?

Comment: Sure, this post was written at a time when Windows XP was still actively supported, and a dual boot bios/CSM system with Windows XP and a later Vista, 7, etc, could refuse to boot if the ntldr for XP was located in the system reserved partition.

Comment: It's an edge case that was only likely to affect a VERY small number of people, but was worth adding a note of caution at the time.  GRUB and other non NT boot loaders don't really care about Windows drive letters, except certain versions of OS/2.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I've removed the drive letter and restarted in the meantime, and (predictably) haven't had any issues.

Answer (score 17):

I encountered the same issue. In DiskMgmt GUI no drive letter was assigned to the hidden system partition but in Windows Explorer it had drive letter H:

I solved it as following: In a command prompt I started `DiskPart.exe`, then ran:

```
list disk
select Disk 0
list partition
select partition 1 (the one corresponding with the hidden system drive)
remove
```

Now the drive letter is gone in the Explorer.

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me.  Worth noting that "Remove" just gets rid of the letter, it doesn't remove the partition!

Answer (score 3):

In some cases - as seen in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/948516/380318) - removing the drive letter for the System Reserved partition can cause other partitions on that drive to not show up in Windows Explorer. To avoid that, a registry tweak must be used to maintain the drive letter but hide the drive.

Open the Registry Editor (type `regedit` in the Run dialog) and navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`, creating the `Explorer` key if necessary. Create a new DWORD value called `NoDrives`. The data for that value should be a bitmask with set bits indicating a hidden drive. To hide only the A drive, set the data to `1`. To hide the B drive, set the data to `2` in decimal (`10` in binary) - the second bit corresponds to the B drive. Similarly, `9` would hide the D and A drives (it's `1001` in binary).

A logoff/logon cycle may be required for this change to take effect.

Comment: What if `E`, `F` or `W` drives?

Comment: @zwcloud `E` is the fifth letter of the alphabet, so you need to set the fifth bit (add 16). For `F`, add 32. I think `W` would add 4,194,304. To hide all three of those, the final hex value would be 0x400030 if my calculations are correct.

Answer (score 3):

***Complete answer (changes are saved after reboot):***

1. Open Windows Powershell or Command line as Administrator

   `Start -> Search -> Powershell or CMD -> Run as Administrator`
2. Open Diskpart

   `diskpart`
3. Select disk

   `select disk 0`
4. Identify the EFI partition showing up in Explorer

   `list partition`
5. Select the EFI partition (Replace 'X' with the correct partition number):

   `select partition X`
6. Remove the EFI partition's drive letter (it won't delete the partition, just remove the mount point):

   `remove`
7. Exit Diskpart

   `exit`
8. Open RegEdit

   `Start -> Search -> Type "regedit"`
9. Find the right key/folder

   `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices`
10. If the EFI partitions drive letter is still in registry, delete the value.

    `For example: \DosDevices\X:`
11. Close RegEdit and reboot.

    Ref: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/window-10-efi-system-partition-and-recovery/e7389cec-f0a3-4f85-bc7e-8b22be22680b

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. To solve it, I did the following:

- Right click on C: Drive and select Properties
- Now you can see the Local Disk(C:) Properties Model Dialog Box
- Now select the tools tab feature in the Local Disk(C:) Properties Model Dialog Box
- Now click on Check Now button and you can see the Check Disk Local Disk (C:) Model Dialog Box
- And at last select the check box Automatically File System Errors and click on the start button.
- Restart the computer and let the check computer file system error .

Hope it will hide the system reserved partition.