# How do I hide 2 system reserve drives in registry?

Tags: windows-7

In reference to this answer [How do I hide the System Reserved partition?](https://superuser.com/a/948543):

> In some cases - as seen in this question - removing the drive letter
>   for the System Reserved partition can cause other partitions on that
>   drive to not show up in Windows Explorer. To avoid that, a registry
>   tweak must be used to maintain the drive letter but hide the drive.
>
> Open the Registry Editor (type regedit in the Run dialog) and navigate
>   to
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer,
>   creating the Explorer key if necessary. Create a new DWORD value
>   called NoDrives. The data for that value should be a bitmask with set
>   bits indicating a hidden drive. To hide only the A drive, set the data
>   to 1. To hide the B drive, set the data to 2 in decimal (10 in binary)
>   - the second bit corresponds to the B drive. Similarly, 9 would hide the D and A drives (it's 1001 in binary).
>
> A logoff/logon cycle may be required for this change to take effect.

I have two drives, and two windows 7 boot ups and so I have 2 system reserve drives that I would like to hide.  Is there a way to add a 2nd DWORD value for the 2nd drive ?  the two drives in question are D and G.

Comment: Note: The answer the OP is referring to is this one [How do I hide the System Reserved partition?](http://superuser.com/a/948543)

Answer (score 3):

#### I would like to hide two drives, D and G.

You don't need a 2nd `DWORD` as the way NoDrives works is a bitmask where the set bits indicate a hidden drive.

So in your case the value you need is `72`.

`72` decimal is `01001000` binary:

- The 4th bit is set (`D` is drive "letter" 4)
- The 7th bit is set (`G` is drive "letter" 7)

There is a calculator at [NoDrives](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-nodrives.html) to make life easier:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

> Copy the result into the registry to hide the
>   drive letter(s)
>
> User Key:
>
> ```
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
> ```
>
> System Key:
>
> ```
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
> ```
>
> Value Name: `NoDrives`
>
> Data Type: `DWORD`
>
> After changing the registry, logoff or reboot so that it takes effect.
>
> Drive mappings hidden with a nodrives registry setting are still
>   available, just type the drive letter into the explorer address bar.

Source [NoDrives](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-nodrives.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [nodrives](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-nodrives.html) - Hide drive mappings in 'My Computer', Windows Explorer and the standard Open dialog box.
- [TechNet - NoDrives](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938267.aspx)